# jquery-jtable -How to the two properties in a cell?

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

Now I have two  property like

```
int xPoint = 1;
int yPoint = 2;
```

They describe a point

Now,using **jquery-jtable** to show the data,

```
xPoint | yPoint  
  1    |   2
```

code:

```
xPoint : {
    title: 'xPoint '
    },
yPoint : {
    title: 'yPoint '
},
```

Now,I want it show like this:

> Point
>   (1,2)

And the code is:

```
xPoint : {
    display:function(data){
        return "("+data.record.xPoint +","+data.record.yPoint +")";
    },
    title: 'Point'
},
```

I tried it and that can be achieved,but I think it's not the best way to solve it ,So I want to know if there are other methods to do it?

how to fit the two properties in a cell?
I try

```
xPoint,yPoint: {
    title: 'Point'
},
```

but it doesn't work ....

So how to do it?

Comment: So what's wrong with your `display` solution? According to documentation it seems to be the right way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm sorry to reply you so late,my question is how to show like this " Point
(1,2)" and can edit it in jquery-jtable ?

Comment: use this "xPoint : {
    display:function(data){
        return "("+data.record.xPoint +","+data.record.yPoint +")";
    },
    title: 'Point'
}," ,i think it can't edit both xPoint and yPoint

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with your issue (and include it in question)? It seems that when you edit a record, all its fields are available for editing, so you'll see your `xPoint` and `yPoint` there (at least this is how it looks like in `jTable` demos).